# Sharing the Identity Login Cookie across subdomains

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-3.0

I am currently working on a ASP.Net Core 3 pre-release 9 MVC Web app. I try to login into my Web App with the same Cookie.

Currently my `Startup.cs` the `ConfigureServices` method looks something like the following:

```cs
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.Name = "Auth";
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                options.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.Strict;
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;

                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(31);
                options.LoginPath = "/Auth/SignIn";
                options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                options.Validate();
            });
```

Then like the other questions on SO said I added something along these lines:

`options.Cookie.Domain = ".localhost";`

I tried it without the dot, with the port and all possible combinations, but it doesn't work. I also changed the `SameSiteMode` to any possible option, but it didn't help neither. I can't even see it in the Browser Cookies, until I remove it, it won't work.

Note: All the Subdomains are handled by the same ASP.Net Core app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was a bit more complicated in some ways, but the solution is actually pretty simple.

Localhost gets special treatments in a lot of ways, but also for cookies. In order for a cookie to be accepted by the client e.g. the browser the `Domain` property needs to contain at least two dots. For localhost you can simple do this by constructing your domain something like `.domain.localhost` which will solve the issue. Of course you will need to call your website now over the same domain in order to work.